# Como referenciar una imagen de la carpeta drawable con FFImageLoading en xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Tengo una imagen llamada test.jpg y quiero pintarla en la ContentPage usando el paquete nuget de FFImageLoading

```
 <ffimageloading:CachedImage 
                 WidthRequest="200"
                    HeightRequest="200"

            Source = "test.jpg">
                </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

Ya agregue el código del init en la MainActivity :

```
FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.CachedImageRenderer.Init(true);
```

pero no pinta nada ?

Answer (score 0):

Para resolverlo tuve que pegar la imagen en una carpeta en el proyecto netstandard de xamarin forms y  marcar la imagen como embedded resource :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego la ruta se debe pasar de esta forma:

```
 <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                    WidthRequest="300"
                    HeightRequest="200"
                    Source="resource://{nombreproyecto}.images.{nombreimagen}.{extension(jpg,png,etc)}"
                    >

                </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```